# How to access a Windows Azure Mobile Service table through a view model with a different name

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I am accessing a Windows Azure Mobile Service and connecting to a table in the database.  If my property name in my view model class doesn't exactly match the column name, I have an easy mechanism to map them:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lessondescription")]
public string LessonDescription {
   get; set;
}
```

This works fine.  However, how do I perform the same mapping when the view model name is different than the table name?  In my case, my class is named "LessonViewModel" but my table is named "Lesson".  I haven't found an attribute that does the same function.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `[JsonObject(Title = "Lesson")]` attribute on your class to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @phillipv said, you can also use the `[DataTable("the_table_name_you_want")]` attribute to define the name of the table corresponding to your class.